# How do I do addition by row in Power BI DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to add Source as per shopping, booking, campaign, and web in Power BI DAX. For example, there are 3 shopping, 2 booking, 3 campaign and 2 web.

```
Source           
Shopping_HVAL   
Shopping_MVAL   
Shopping_LVAL   
Booking_HVAL    
Booking_LVAL    
Campaign_HVAL   
Campaign_MVAL   
Campaign_LVAL   
Web_HVAL        
Web_MVAL
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What is the end result that you want?

Comment: The end result should be that Shopping column should add to 3, Booking (2), Campaign (3) and Web (2).

Comment: Are you trying to display it in a visual or create a calculated table or what?

Comment: Yes, I want to create a calculated column.

Comment: So add a column to your current table: `3;3;3;2;2;3;3;3;2;2`?

Comment: How do you do a count per row name in dax? I am trying to do this on thousands of data set.

Comment: I'm asking if that's what you are after. Is that column I suggested the output you want?